# How do I print out the original index of all items of a sorted python list

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a list

```
a=[2,7,23,4563,23].
```

How do I print the index of all the elements in one line?

Basically, I have to sort the list and print the original index as the output. Example:

```
A=[4,5,3,7,1]
```

After sorting the new array becomes

```
A=[1,3,4,5,7]
```

The required output should be

```
4 2 0 1 3
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Basically, I have to sort the list and print the original index as the output. Example:

A={4,5,3,7,1}

After sorting the new array becomes A={1,3,4,5,7}.

The required output should be "4 2 0 1 3"

Comment: The `enumerate()` function will be helpful here.

Comment: @NeelanjanMitra What you have just written in the comment needs to be in the question.

Comment: `print(" ".join(str(t[1]) for t in sorted([(val, i) for i, val in enumerate(A)])))` - what this does is make a list of 2-tuples (value, index), sort them (first item i.e. value will be primary sort key) and extract second item - then formats the string as required.

Comment: For a more readable version of what I wrote above, see Walter Tross's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: 
If you want to sort and then display their original positions you can use <strike>`numpy.array`</strike> Thanks to @tdelaney for identifying that numpy would actually be slower
In a single line:

```
print(" ".join(str(i) for i,v in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[-1])))
```

For

```
a=[2,7,23,4563,23]
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 4 3
```

---

If you want to print the elements value and index in the form `value:index` in one line you can try:

```
print(' '.join(str(v)+':'+str(i)for i,v in enumerate(a)))
```

Output:

```
2:0 7:1 23:2 4563:3 23:4
```

Comment: But `enumerate(np.array(a))` produces the same thing as `enumerate(a)`. Numpy only slows things down here.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad Thank you @tdelaney

Answer (score 4):

Just keep around the original indices in tuples (pairs):

```
input_list = a
print(' '.join(map(str, input_list)))
val_idx_pairs = [(val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(input_list)]
sorted_pairs = sorted(val_idx_pairs)
sorted_values  = [p[0] for p in sorted_pairs]
sorted_indices = [p[1] for p in sorted_pairs]
print(' '.join(map(str, sorted_indices)))
# output:
# 2 7 23 4563 23
# 0 1 2 4 3
```

The trick is that tuples are sorted by comparing their first element, and if that is equal, the second, and so on. A nice side-effect is that the above algorithm implies a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) in case of equal values, just like [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) does.

Answer (score 2):

I like @AstikGabani 's solution but since `numpy` has been mentioned, I thought I toss in a `pandas` solution. This is overkill for small lists, but if the list is large or you want to do other work with the data later, this is a start.

Just create a dataframe, sort the column and the index will go with it.... at least until its reindexed.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> A=[4,5,3,7,1]
>>> dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
>>> dfA
   0
0  4
1  5
2  3
3  7
4  1
>>> dfA.sort_values(0, inplace=True)
>>> dfA
   0
4  1
2  3
0  4
1  5
3  7
>>> " ".join(str(i) for i in dfA.index)
'4 2 0 1 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below-sorted method to achieve your goal.

```
x = [2,7,23,4563,23]

output_lst = sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(" ".join([str(i[0]) for i in output_lst]))
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 4 3
```

Comment: @tdelaney I have added this code.